# What are the differences between PC and console versions?

Tags: version-differences, ark-survival-evolved

Apart from graphics and updatable content they keep updating periodically, what are the differences on gameplay between the PC and console versions of the game?

Comment: I believe besides the fact that games tend to not be cross-compatible (console players can't play with PC players), there is no difference.  Especially with the Xbox One and PS4, there can be/are updates for games.

Comment: Maybe new menus dynamics and interfaces due to the controllers, fluidity, performance and speed of the game, physics that behave different, different style of servers to connect, options to configure in the game, or even exclusive function that each version can have, for example.

Answer (score -2):

Apart from graphics, the only differences are the keyboard/pad gameplay, and the time between loading etc owing to the components of your computer.

There are exclusivity on consoles and on pc too.